# python regex match number greater than 120

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have data

```
67.65 GB
99.29 GB
103.99 GB
5.11 GB
155.66 GB
etc...
```

I'm planning on coming up with a regex to match number grater than 120. Would regex be good for it or should I try other methods?

Comment: Why a regex? Regexes are horrible at arithmetic.

Comment: @melpomene what do you suggest?

Comment: The `>` operator is pretty good at comparing numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use regex. Split the string, cast the 0 index as a float, and compare it to 120.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you need to do is splitting the string,casting first part to float and comparing against 120:

```
float("67.65 GB".split()[0]) > 120
```

Regex is designed for pattern matching, not for arithmetics.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for numbers with at least one digit right of the decimal place:

```
^((12[1-9]|1[3-9]\d|[2-9]\d\d|[1-9]\d\d\d+)\.\d+|120\.\d*[1-9]\d*)$
```

explanation: 
first group, first alternation: 121-129

second alternation: 130-199

third alternation: 200-999

fourth alternation: 1000+

each of these are followed by a "." and any number of digits to the right

The second group covers the case where the integer part is exactly 120, followed by a "." and any number of digits, at least one of which must be non-zero.